# Using item "labels" in beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize

I want to use the same image that's used in `\item` in my beamer presentation in other parts of the text (basically, at the start of a non-itemize paragraph, or in a `tabular`, whatever.

I am using now this hack that I digged out looking at the beamer sources:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Madrid}
  \usecolortheme{crane}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
} 
%% digged out from beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty
\makeatletter
\def\itemmarker{\leavevmode\hbox{\raise0.2pt\beamer@usesphere{item projected}{bigsphere}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
        \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Test}
        \begin{itemize}
                \item one
                \item two
        \end{itemize}

        \itemmarker\ This use the same graphic of the itemize item

        \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: example xoomed in]

...but this is suboptimal, because it will break if I change the theme or even the inner theme. What I would like is something like `\insertitemlabel` which is not provided as far as I know.

Is there a way to define a generic `\useitemlabel` macro that gives access to the current label that is used for itemized elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Keep calm and let beamer do it for you]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Madrid}
    \usecolortheme{crane}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Test}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item one
            \item two
        \end{itemize}

        \leavevmode\usebeamertemplate{itemize item} This use the same graphic of the itemize item

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```